# What am I doing wrong when proving the add_right_cancel theorem?

Tags: lean, lean4, beginner

So, as mentioned in my previous two questions, I have been using The Natural Number Game to help me teach myself how to use the mathematical proof assistant Lean4.

I am currently trying to complete the Advanced Addition world so I can get access to the "≤ World"<sup>1</sup> so I can more easily prove the clunky version of Fermat's Last Theorem<sup>2</sup>, and for some reason I am currently stuck on proving the `add_right_theorem` ([Level 1](https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/leanprover-community/NNG4/world/AdvAddition/level/1) of Advanced Addition World), which states that$$a+n=b+n\implies a=b$$which I don't exactly know how I would state the proof or write it out in Lean4

Here's what I have done so far:

1. The first part (the proof by induction) is pretty easy. All I need to do is this:

```
induction n with d hd
repeat rw [add_zero]
intro h
exact h
```

however the second part$$a+\operatorname{succ}(d)=b+\operatorname{succ}(d)\implies a=b$$is where I am struggling. All I can do is add the successions together to rewrite it as$$\operatorname{succ}(a+d)=\operatorname{succ}(b+d)\implies a=b$$before being forced to introduce the hypothesis `h` to rewrite it as this:

```
hd: a + d = b + d → a = b
h: succ (a + d) = succ (b + d)
Goal: a = b
```

Now, when I apply `succ_inj at h`, it leaves me with

```
hd: a + d = b + d → a = b
h: a + d = b + d
Goal: a = b
```

and now I'm stuck, because I can't use `decide` since that returns the exact same thing, and `triv` doesn't work since the case "True" doesn't exist. (I got a bit desperate, sorry.)

Here is my proof so far:

```
induction n with d hd
repeat rw [add_zero]
intro h
exact h
repeat rw [add_succ]
intro h
apply succ_inj at h
```

So my question is: Where am I messing up the proof of the `add_right_cancel` theorem, and how should I actually go about proving it?

---

<sup>1</sup>I'll replace this with `\le` if it would look neater, the unicode for the "less than or equal to" symbol is `u+00264` for anyone who wants to know.

<sup>2</sup>The more clunky version of Fermat's Last Theorem (that is, the first case of it) comes up in [Power World level 10/10](https://adam.math.hhu.de/#/g/leanprover-community/NNG4/world/Power/level/10), and states that for no $a,b,c,n\in\mathbb N$,$$(a+1)^{n+3}+(b+1)^{n+3}=(c+1)^{n+3}$$which is where the Inequality World would come in handy, because it would greatly shorten the proof. [The first case has been proven in Lean.](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2305.08955.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From

```
hd: a + d = b + d → a = b
h: a + d = b + d
Goal: a = b
```

you can use the `apply` tactic.